# Azure Data Factory V2 - Copy Task fails HTTP file to Azure Blob Store

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my code I have an HTTP file activity in the "Source" of a copy task. This hits an Azure Function HTTP endpoint and returns a String when complete. I want to store that String result into a "Sink" of Azure Blob.

My Linked Service looks like so.

[image: Linked Service]

My Dataset looks like so.

[image]

I get the following error when debugging

"{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidHttpRequestHeaderFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to set addtional http header,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.\r\nParameter name: name,Source=System,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Data1"
}"

Answer (score 2):

according to the error message, the problem lies on the requestHeader setting. Please note that the format of the requestHeader in HTTP dataset should be like **"key1:value1\nkey2:value2\nkey3:value3"**, so in your case, pass **"Content-Type": "application/json"** to requestHeader should be the right format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's yet another unfortunate ADF/Synapse Pipelines quirk. Unlike for Web activities, or REST Datasets, here we have a single input for headers, as opposed to header/value input rows in those other tools.

After fiddling around with various combinations, the ONLY one that worked when using **DYNAMIC input** was the following:

```
@{string('Authorization: Bearer justanexample')}
```